# GPG invalid signature error while running apt update inside arm32v7/ubuntu:20.04 docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to upgrade from ubuntu16 to ubuntu20 and for that I need to change image `arm32v7/ubuntu:16.04` to `arm32v7/ubuntu:20.04` in all our Dockerfiles [update required libraries after that], But while working on this task I found that there's some issue with arm32v7 base image of ubuntu:20.04 - when I run `apt-get update` it fails with following error messages-

```
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I tried the solution mentioned here [https://askubuntu.com/a/1264921/872700] but that too is not working as we are using the image in Dockerfile and its not allowed to pass `--security-opt` in `docker build` command.

As a workaround I ran `docker run` with `--security-opt` option and created another image with `docker commit` - then ran `apt-get update` inside new image but that too is not working.

FYI, The machine has following docker version on it-
`Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46`

Comment: checkout duplicate on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263284/apt-update-throws-signature-error-in-ubuntu-20-04-container-on-arm

Comment: same issue occurred with php8 docker container

Answer (score 63):

I had this issue on Docker Desktop for Mac recently, running `apt-get update` in an Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64 container. It turned out the VM hosting the Docker images on macOS had run out of disk space. That somehow manifested itself as `apt` reporting invalid signatures on package index files. Pruning unused images to free space solved the issue for me:

> docker image prune -a

As mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64439278/gpg-invalid-signature-error-while-running-apt-update-inside-arm32v7-ubuntu20-04/64553153#comment116083404_64553153) by [sema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343314/sema), if the issue is caused by insufficient disk space, another workaround is to increase the size of the virtual disk used by the virtual machine that is running docker. In Docker Desktop for Mac this can be done via  `Preferences > Resources > Disk image size`.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue as the OP and this solves the problem. In addition, increasing disk space for images can also help: Preferences > Resources > Disk image size.

Comment: `docker system prune -a` will remove unused containers and clean up a lot of space. I ran into this and this fixed the issue, also cleared out 30GB of files.

Comment: Waw, damn, thank you so much for pointing that out, that probably saved me a couple of hours of soul searching.

Answer (score 13):

To solve the problem, I had to update the library `libseccomp2` on my host pi machine as I could not find any other solution to apply inside the base image.

Downloaded the deb package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/armhf/libseccomp2/download) and applied on host machine using -

`sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.4.4-1+b1_armhf.deb`

Comment: Is there any word on when this will be rolled out by default?

Comment: Update: If you setup [debian backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/), then running `sudo apt-get install -t buster-backports libseccomp2` will install a newer version of `libseccomp2` to fix the issue. Just to be on the safe side, I restarted `docker` and `containerd` too: `sudo systemctl restart containerd docker`.

Comment: duplicate answer on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263284/apt-update-throws-signature-error-in-ubuntu-20-04-container-on-arm